# How to get object return from multiple entities by joining query with using spring data jpa?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have some entities. I want to get joining result from those entities.**I have to use Hibernate and spring data**. How can I get result by joining those entities? I have not found any proper tutorial or example. 
I am new to spring and hibernate .

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: yes i did, i have used projection